# QGIS GRASS: Error when converting vector to raster

Tags: qgis, gdal, grass-gis, rasterization

I am trying to convert a vectorial layer (a grid of regular points with values, representing probabilities, associated to each point).
I tried to use QGIS, but I got this error:

```
ERROR 1: Attempt to create 0x0 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero.
```

I checked and I don't have any probability for any point as zero.

I then tried to use GRASS (in "source of raster values" I selected "attr" and then in "Attributes" I selected the column in the file which has the probabilitites), but it does not work again:

```
ERROR: Column type (CHARACTER) not supported (did you mean 'labelcolumn'?)
```

I used "v.info" to see the information about the vectorial layer and this is the result (I don't know if it helps):
[image]

Do you have any idea why this is happenning?

Here is a preview of the dataset:

```
ID  PROBUSE1
499 0.032075
500 0.020963
501 0.027376
502 0.0507
503 0.058432
504 0.043781
505 0.029973
506 0.028873
507 0.026719
508 0.025188
509 0.037346
510 0.028899
511 0.021097
512 0.017613
513 0.014795
514 0.017285
515 0.019617
763 0.035415
764 0.049729
765 0.050707
```

Comment: No, they are all spaced between 100m; I created a regular grid! Then used "join" to attribute the probabilities. But I see what you refer, I hadn't noticed it. It does not make sense! Do you have any suggestions on how to change this?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the metadata. Can you share test data to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @underdark I shared a preview of the dataset; probabilities vary between 0.01(...) to 0.99(...); do you need any more information?

Comment: Well, that's just the attributes. What vector gis format do you use? Shapefile?

Comment: @underdark yes, I the point layer with the probabilities is a shapefile.

Comment: Please share the shapefile. Makes reproducing the issue easier.

Comment: @underdark the preview of the data I updated is from the shapefile, it has only that information. I used the same type of data in other shp and it worked. Is this the information you wanted?

Comment: Did you create the regular grid of points yourself, or did you download it from external source? It could be that the points report attribute data, but are missing the actual geometries themselves (i.e., the latitude / longitude values that geolocate the points). Alternatively, it could be that the data is in the wrong format that the algorithms expect (e.g., numeric data can possible reported as strings rather than registered as Integer or Floating point data). If you can zip the shapefile and add the data here as an attachment for more help.

Comment: @jbukoski I created the grid; then I used "join" to attach the probability values I wanted. I did the same for other files, the exact way. and they work perfectly... How do I attach files here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because @underdark has repeatedly asked for a reproducible dataset and OP did not provide one (nor she said it would not provide because of some reason). Hence, either the error is not reproducible, or maybe it is a bug and it is also off-topic here.